# How to set a child view element from an existing element in the DOM

Tags: ember.js, kineticjs

Suppose I have the following DOM :

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="created-by-other-tools">I want this to be my child</div>
</div>
```

The div "container" comes from an Ember.ContainerView :

```
container = Ember.ContainerView.create {
        elementId: 'container'
}
```

The div "created-by-other-tools" comes from another javascript code that has nothing todo with Ember :

```
newDiv = document.createElement('div')
container.appendChild(newDiv)
```

Is it possible to link this newDiv with a child view of my container ? I want some thing like this :

```
 child = Ember.View.create()
 Ember.set(child,'element',newDiv)
```

My idea is to handle event of newDiv with my child view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created an example using KinectJS with Ember.js, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/e6Dfh/

```js
Ember.View.create({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        var id = this.get('elementId');
        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: id,
            width: 578,
            height: 200
        });

        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        ...
    }
}).append();
```

Also take a look at this blog post: http://blog.sproutcore.com/using-raphael-js-with-sproutcore-2-0/ . All tough it's written for SproutCore 2.0, it might help you.

Comment: What I really want to do is to use kineticjs http://www.kineticjs.com/ with ember . Kineticjs needs a container that's why I give it the id of my Ember.ContainerView (it can be just a view). Then it creates a content element inside my container div. I need to handle events from this content. I can do this manually with element.addEventListener(...) but I'd a like to use a more Emberish way. So I'm wondering whethere it's possible to wrap this content inside an Ember.View and handle event as usual with Ember.

Comment: So what events are we talking about?